# Get data from specific webpage

Tags: java

I need to get data from table id="maintable" from website "http://trackinn.az/GeoLoc/reports.aspx?login=ho&password=ho". I tried many methods some of them worked for other websites but not for this one. Could someone help pls?
Thanks.

Comment: Get html content from the URL and parse it with JSoup.

Comment: Yep, data is retrieved as JSON via POST request, you can try HtmlUnit.

Comment: Maybe you can show some example?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get data from that table. It is being dynamically created by javascript (AJAX particularly). And I don't think there is any api wich can process javascript.

It would be possible to get data if it was a static file or the part you want would be static, but it is not.

If you are using this site to get geolocation, then use [google geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) for this. it would be better option.

Comment: Not actually i need exactly data given in it. I tried to save a webpage and get data from there but i could only save html file not js and others and without those js files saved webpage doesn't return table. Maybe you could give some other advise? Or the way i could save complete webpage?

Comment: If you want just that matter without coding, than it is even easier. just use firefox inspector tool > select table shown in image > right click on the code of table (i.e. table element) being shown at bottom > select `copy outer HTML` > than paste on notepad or any editor. that's it

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/netdda1a/), I did this for you. (if you only wanted to get the data from browser only, not with coding)

Comment: No i need to get it with coding. But thank you for help.